# Using Singleton Classes in Multiple Modules in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, singleton, metaclass

This might be a silly question since I just learnt about Metaclasses....

If you have 2 Singleton classes each in their own file, is it poor practice to duplicate the `Singleton` metaclass definition in both files, like

**Apple.py**

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class Apple(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass

print(Apple() == Apple())   # True
```

**Orange.py**

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class Orange(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass

print(Orange() == Orange()) # True
```

Or should we move the Singleton metaclass code into its own file `Singleton.py`, and import them into `Apple.py` and `Orange.py`?

Or use a `@singleton` decorator from the package [`singleton-decorator`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/singleton-decorator/1.0.0)?

Comment: `is it poor practice to duplicate the Singleton metaclass definition in both files, like ` Yes. Repeating yourself is never a good thing.

Comment: @sytech Thanks, I just have yet to come across code that imports metaclass definitions from another file.

Comment: @Nyxynyx That's exactly what the `abc` module in the standard library does. Metaclasses are magical in some ways, but not in this.

Comment: @chepner I am a little confused here. Are you suggesting to let the `Singleton` class be a subclass of `ABCMeta` instead of `type`? I am not familiar with the `abc` module, will appreciate an explanation

Comment: No, just that `abc` is an example of a module that provides a metaclass. `import abc; class Foo(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta)`. It's maybe not as obvious in Python 3 as it was in Python 2, since the Python 3 version provides `abc.ABC` which you can use as a base class to avoid using the metaclass directly. There's no reason not to put `Singleton` in its own module, to be imported as needed.

Comment: @chepner If you dont put `Singleton` in its own module to be imported as needed, then do you repeat the `Singleton` metaclass code in all the modules that needs it? Or is there a 3rd way that I am not getting?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you put `Singleton` in its own module? Don't copy and paste code. That's just Wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is a silly practice to use metaclasses to define singletons. I don't know who originally came up with this pattern, it is now widespread, and it is way overkill.

That said, just for a quick answer: of course it does not make sense to duplicate code - much less so when you won't be changing even a single parameter -it is the exact same code. Just keep it in a file and import it from the other, even if you don't want to create an specific file just for that.

Now, metaclasses are a powerful feature in Python that is best used when one knows what is going on.  Otherwise, there are side effects, the most common of which is being unable to combine your classes with others that have a metaclass (which might actually be a necessary one).

That said, this is a non-metaclass singleton pattern based on decorators:

```
_register = {}

def singleton(cls):
   def wrapper(*args, **kw):
       if cls not in _register:
           instance = cls(*args, **kw)
           _register[cls] = instance
       return _register[cls] 

   wrapper.__name__ = cls.__name__
   return wrapper

...
@singleton
class Orange:
    ...
```

The code above is provided as is, but if using it beware it does not warn about someone trying to create a second instance with different parameters. It could be changed to allow no parameters, or to raise an error on re-instantiation.

Better yet, the decorator pattern can create the singleton instance right on class declaration, unlike what goes with metaclasses.Then, there is not even the need for a register, since the class won't be available for one to try to produce an incorrect second-instance of it (although one could do `type(Orange)()` - if you are in a project which is a context for who can break the code:

```
def singleton(cls):
      return cls()
```

That is it.

```
@singleton
class Orange:
    ...
```

after executed, this will add "Orange" to the namespace as the one and singly allowed instance for the "Orange" class as declared. Or for that matter, just do:

```
class Orange:
   ...

Orange = Orange()
```

(and voilá - you even resolved your problem of sharing code across modules - there is no extra code needed at all)